# What do I need, distinct or group by?

Tags: mysql, sql

I can't figure out if i need a distinct or a group by
Or maybe im completely off.

Here is my current query

```
SELECT * FROM `product_sales`
WHERE `VisitorSessionId` IN
 (
  SELECT `VisitorSessionId` from `product_sales`
  WHERE `ProductId` = 68 AND `SiteId` = 1
 )
AND `SiteId` = 1
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,200
```

And this would be an example of my result set i would get with that current query

```
Id  SiteId  VisitorSessionId    TimeStamp   OrderId ProductId   CustomerId
65655   1   -327    1430798400  30133   84  19262
65654   1   -327    1430798400  30133   84  19262
65653   1   -327    1430798400  30133   68  19262
65652   1   -327    1430798400  30133   68  19262
65333   1   -435    1429848000  29969   68  19211
65332   1   -435    1429848000  29969   68  19211
65331   1   -435    1429848000  29969   90  19211
65330   1   -435    1429848000  29969   90  19211
65100   1   -504    1429329600  29871   5632    12688
65099   1   -504    1429329600  29871   5632    12688
```

But What I want is to have only one row per `OrderId` And `ProductId`

So I can get multiple row of of the same `OrderId` but not the same `ProductId` in the same `OrderId`

So for example this is what id like to get

```
Id  SiteId  VisitorSessionId    TimeStamp   OrderId ProductId   CustomerId
65654   1   -327    1430798400  30133   84  19262
65652   1   -327    1430798400  30133   68  19262
65332   1   -435    1429848000  29969   68  19211
65330   1   -435    1429848000  29969   90  19211
65099   1   -504    1429329600  29871   5632    12688
```

When using a group by I only get the first record in each `OrderId`

How can I get that expected result ?

Comment: @NickVolynkin Your right it does not, I putted tags first in my post and I was going to include the current way I am dealing with this to help understand my question but I finally did not.

Il will remove php tag now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL, you *can* use `group by` for this purpose:

```
SELECT ps.*
FROM `product_sales` ps
WHERE `VisitorSessionId` IN (SELECT `VisitorSessionId` 
                             FROM `product_sales`
                             WHERE `ProductId` = 68 AND `SiteId` = 1
                            ) AND
      `SiteId` = 1
GROUP BY productId, orderId
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 0,200;
```

However, this uses a MySQL extension, with columns in the `group by` that are not in the `group by`.  These come from *indeterminate* rows, and they are not even guaranteed to be from the same row (although they are going to be from "correct" rows that match the group).

Perhaps this satisfies your need.  Otherwise, you will need a bit more complex query.  I might suggest this variation:

```
SELECT ps.orderid, ps.siteid, ps.VisitorSessionId, ps.TimeStamp, ps.OrderId,
       group_concat(ProductId)
FROM `product_sales` ps
WHERE `SiteId` = 1
GROUP BY ps.orderid, ps.siteid, ps.VisitorSessionId, ps.TimeStamp, ps.OrderId
HAVING SUM(`ProductId` = 68 AND `SiteId` = 1) > 0
ORDER BY orderId DESC
LIMIT 0, 200;
```

This produces one row per order satisfying `ProductId` = 68 AND SiteId = 1`, with the products included as a linked list.

Comment: Thanks the first awnser is exactly what I was after, Also thanks for the alternate method I like it, But due to the fact that i would have to change some stuff in code, Il stick to the first one Thanks for your time! :)